# Wrong output on adding 2 days in current date or today date using python

Tags: python

I am adding 2 days in current date or today date using python but getting wrong output, please at look at code below i used ::

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
time_diff =str(timedelta(days=2))
d =str(date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") ) + time_diff
print(d.split("day")[0])
```

OUTPUT ::2020-04-262

i think it should show the output ::2020-04-28.

Comment: You are adding 2 strings together - combine the 2 date objects, then convert to a string if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all those `str()` calls. You want to add the time delta to a time, you *don't* want to add two strings together (that just concatenates).

Just add the time delta to the date:

```
from datetime import timedelta

time_diff = timedelta(days=2)
a_date = date.today() + time_diff
a_date_string = a_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

print(a_date_string)
# 2020-04-28
```

Comment: If you add using strings, then you concatenate. If you add two date objects, then it should go as expected/suppossed.